# Truncated citation using misc

Tags: bibtex

I'm using @misc for citing a website in my work. This is the bib entry and the text citing it.

```
@misc{OpenMP,
title = {{OpenMP API for parallel programming, version 2.0}},
note = {\url{http://openmp.org/wp/}},
}
```

and

```
 OpenMP \cite{OpenMP} is a parallel programming model.
```

When compiled using latex, bibtex, latex and latex, I get a truncated citation like this

```
OpenMP (Ope) is a parallel programming model.
```

when I am expecting

```
OpenMP (OpenMP) is a parallel programming model.
```

How can I rectify this. Ideally I would want the entire 'OpenMP' instead if 'Ope' in the cited text.

Thanks

Comment: Does using the `key` filed helps? i.e., add `key= {OpenMP}` to the entry;

Answer (score 1):

According to the bibtex manual (i.e., `texdoc bibtex`) the field `key` is

> Used for alphabetizing, cross referencing, and creating a label when the “author” information (described in Section 4) is missing.

Thus the entry can be written

```
@misc{OpenMP,
  key   = {OpenMP},
  title = {{OpenMP} {API} for parallel programming, version 2.0},
  note  = {\url{http://openmp.org/wp/}},
}
```